# Why setState not set appending my array into state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to create a text area which taken multiple links then I `split()` into array yeah Its working fine, but I want to set that array into my `state` in `linkList: []` but when I click to button for submitting it gives me empty array as I initialize. but when I again press to submit button then it gives me my desired list, why? here are code and outputs

```
onSubmit = event => {
    this.setState({ loading: true, host: undefined });
    const { text, linkList } = this.state;

    console.log(text);
    const mList = text.split("\n").filter(String);
    console.log(mList);
    this.setState({
      linkList: [...mList]
    });
    console.log(linkList);

    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

Output console (First Click)

```
youtube.com
google.com
facebook.com
------------------------------------------------------------
["youtube.com", "google.com", "facebook.com"]
------------------------------------------------------------
[]
```

Output Console (Second Click)

```
youtube.com
google.com
facebook.com
--------------------------------------------- 
["youtube.com", "google.com", "facebook.com"]
---------------------------------------------
["youtube.com", "google.com", "facebook.com"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is being appended, it's just not available until the next render.

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. **This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall**. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous. That means it doesn't happen right away, but a very short time later instead. If you add a:

```
console.log(linkList)
```

to the top of your render method, you will see the items being appended just as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help.

```
onSubmit = event => {
    this.setState({ loading: true, host: undefined }, () => {
      const { text, linkList } = this.state;

      console.log(link);
      const mList = text.split("\n").filter(String);
      console.log(mList);
      this.setState({
        linkList: [...mList]
      }, () => {
        console.log(linkList);
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  };
```