# React JS component declare a variable required to assign value on useEffect to use across multiple functions

Tags: reactjs

In a React Component, Need to declare variable to access across multiple functions. Two approaches tried to achieve this - `useState` (less good because of rendering) or `let/var`. Example:

```
  const [userName, setuserName] = useState("");
  let root = "";
```

problem (part 1): on `useEffect` after setting `setuserName` hook I can not access `userName` immediately. but after modifying root I can use the variable immediately. Example:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      
      //get name from firebase doc ref...

      let name = user.claims.userName; //"AName"
      setuserName(name);
      root = name ;
      console.log("userName: " + userName+ " , " + root); //here userName is empty but root has the name.

  return () => {
  // db.ref("").off("value", listener);
};

}, []);
```

problem (part 2): if both used in a function declared in the component problem part 1 reverses, I mean, the `userName` (hook) will have name in it but the root variable will be empty. Example:

```
 async function handleSubmit(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    console.log("root  = " + root  + " , userName : " + userName );//here root is empty but userName has the name.
    return; //or call methods to firebase ref.
}
```

Tested with assigning variables and state with string literals from code within (Eg: `root = "testName"`). Just need a temporary variable to call firebase functions. Why this behaviour happens and what approach should I use here?

---

Update:

Re rendering of component will reset the variable, using state hook is kinda overkill but only option.

Now to set the value  of state (`userName`), useEffect is used in the first place. It also calls and fetches other variables from firebase based on the state (`userName`). If you dont have that reference nothing else works. You dont have that reference because useState will have it on next render, so not usable right here. You can store `userName` on a variable. Again render will reset that variable, so wont work with variable either. Hope this make sense.

Now I have solved this, thought it would be interesting to put on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why setState not set appending my array into state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723975/why-setstate-not-set-appending-my-array-into-state)

Comment: Thats part of the problem. The fact that a a variable is required to use across multiple functions is key here. That question solves only why state is not updating. Also title says about variable and that one is about `state` hook.

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous, so in the first snippet `userName` state won't have updated yet. Using a locally global variable `root` will be reset each render cycle, hence why `root` is undefined in the second snippet. Your question is unclear and it seems you are missing a few React basics. Try posting code that you are actually trying to work with versus a possibly over-simplified version.

Answer (score 1):

first issue is related to the fact the `setState` doesn't update state synchronous, which is a common doubt, hence console.log will not print next state. And you can't `await` on some state fwiw, since it's not an actually promise. If you need to perform some action based on a state change you should create another use `useEffect` with that state as dependency:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      
   //get name from firebase doc ref...

   let name = user.claims.userName; //"AName"
   setuserName(name);

   return () => {
   // db.ref("").off("value", listener);
 };

}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // another useEffect based on userName as dependency
  //do something on userName update...
  console.log(userName);
}, [userName]);
```

second issue is that on rerenders only the state value is reflected correctly. Once `setuserName` is resolved and your component is rerendered, any declared variables like `root` will be recreated based on its original logic (*unless you memoize it with **useMemo** to avoid some expensive calculation*).

you should better use state across places/functions to control the logic of your component, not variables declared at your component body which would lead to unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. useEffect with state `userName` is the solutions then, will have to keep an eye for infinite loop.

Comment: I have removed the async keyword and it it still not printing the variable. And I need the async because a firebase ref method need to execute.

Comment: actually, I was not entirely clear. you need to create another useEffect, for logic to run based on that specific state as dependency.

Comment: React state updates ***are*** asynchronous, but the state updater functions are 100% ***not*** `async` functions. They return no Promise to chain nor `await` on. It may be being a little pedantic on the terminology, but when a subject is already a confusing matter to novice devs, muddling terminology doesn't really help.

Comment: @rifat you can keep declaring your functions as _async_ to await your firebase action to resolve. I meant that some people would think, that since the state update is not sync they could do `await  setuserName(name)`, or use chain it like a promise and that wouldn't work since they are not promise. Which is basically what @DrewReese explained above.