# React Hook not updating state for some reason

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Hi I am trying to make an API call and the function holds few state changes but the state changes not working as expected

```
const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [previewData, setPreviewData] = useState({});
const [reportGenerateProgress, setReportGenerateProgress] = useState('');

const fetchData = async (e) => {
        const reports = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        const reportProgress = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        setLoading(true)
        const params = {
            key: e.key,
            value: e.value,
            preview: true,
            report_type: e.key === 'account' ? "ACCOUNT" : "TAG",
            case_sensitive: false
        }
        for (const [i, report] of reports.entries()) {
            console.log(loading, previewData) // false, {}
            setReportGenerateProgress(reportStatus[i + 1])
            params['report_id'] = report;
            const data = {[report]: "test"};
            setPreviewData({...previewData, [report]: data});
            console.log(loading, previewData) // false, {}
        }
        console.log(loading, previewData) //false, {}
    }
```

can somebody point out the issue? I am not able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you setting `previewData` twice?

Comment: sorry @RoboRobok, that sniplet is debugging code

Comment: Okay, but where are you fetching anything?

Comment: this function is executed as an action of button click synthetic event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why setState not set appending my array into state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723975/why-setstate-not-set-appending-my-array-into-state)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute `console.log` state just after `setState`.

You can see the changes in `useEffect` hook by using something similar

```
useEffect({console.log(loading, previewData)}, [loading, previewData]);
```

Comment: Hi @Malay. I tried that way but the result remains the same.